# jQuery contains fails with webcomponents.js polyfill in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-component

I'm using the [WebComponent's Polyfill](http://webcomponents.org/).

The following code snippet works fine in latest stable Chrome, but fails in latest stable Firefox.

It seems like such a core piece of functionality that I feel like I'm doing something incorrect, but I'm worried that the polyfill has incorrectly modified Sizzle functionality.

If anyone has any insight into the matter, please share.

```js
window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var contains = $.contains(document.documentElement, document.getElementById('root'));
    console.log('Contains:', contains);
  });
});
```

```html
<div id='root'></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webcomponentsjs/0.7.20/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

EDIT: There's apparently more to this than meets the eye. Some people are reporting that they see `true` not `false` in Firefox. Unclear what the root cause is.

Comment: this seems to work in FF 45.0.1: http://pagedemos.com/t777773yj2me/

Comment: Yeah, that's because jQuery doesn't get shimmed by the polyfill. That causes lots of other bad errors to happen, unfortunately. Ref: https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/issues/48#issuecomment-81977289

Comment: I think that if I can strip out the shadow dom polyfill it might work. Going to look into it.

Comment: fwiw, i use the limited [registerElement() poly](https://github.com/WebReflection/document-register-element) in a lot of projects to good effect.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by WebComponent's ShadowDOM polyfill. If `webcomponents-lite.js` is used instead of the full polyfill then all works as expected.

Ref: https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs#element-wrapping--unwrapping-limitations-

Suspect that the element in question has been wrapped which breaks its reference.